# Counting TRUE() and False() in Power BI Using COUNTAX and FILTER

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a column (Column_Name) in a table (Table_Name) that contains boolean (0 | 1) values. I am trying  to get a count for each value. For example, I have 1500 total rows and I'd like to have 2 Measures that show 700 are True while 800 are False.

I've tried the following, but each just gives me the total number of rows (1500):

```
False_Measure = COUNTAX(FILTER('Table_Name','Table_Name'[Column_Name]=FALSE()),FALSE())

True_Measure = COUNTAX(FILTER('Table_Name','Table_Name'[Column_Name]=FALSE()),TRUE())
```

I'm totally confused...

I'm not even sure I'm using the correct DAX functions at this point.

Comment: I came upon an interesting feature in the solution. If you are using the Measure in many of the visuals within Power BI, you should add a +0 to the end of the Measure. Otherwise, if the Measure returns with no matches, the resultant value is not a number. The +0 forces it to return 0. For example, this will give you a numeric value, even if there are no matches to the Measure:  False_Measure = COUNTAX(FILTER('Table_Name', 'Table_Name'[Column_Name]=FALSE()), [Column_Name])

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in the second parameter of the COUNTAX() function.It should be the column/item you want to count instead of the same listed filter item.

So these functions should give you the results you want:

```
False_Measure = COUNTAX(FILTER('Table_Name', 'Table_Name'[Column_Name]=FALSE()), [Column_Name])

True_Measure = COUNTAX(FILTER('Table_Name', 'Table_Name'[Column_Name]=TRUE()), [Column_Name])
```

The documentation for this function is listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/countax-function-dax).

Comment: This solution is perfect. The route that I was considering required 3 additional measures and did not support drill down. So, this is superior in every way. (NOTE: I did find that the DAX I used in the question DOES work. When I created the question, I was having data issues on import, which was breaking my syntax.)

Answer (score 5):

Here's are some possiblities:

```
True_Measure = SUMX(Table_Name, 1*Table_Name[Column_Name])
True_Measure = SUMX(Table_Name, 1*(Table_Name[Column_Name] = TRUE()))

False_Measure = SUMX(Table_Name, 1*(Table_Name[Column_Name] = FALSE()))
False_Measure = COUNTROWS(Table_Name) - [True_Measure]
```

In most of these, I'm using `1*` to coerce a `True/False` boolean value to be a number `0` or `1`.

---

You can use a `COUNTROWS` on a filtered table too.

```
True_Measure  = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table_Name, Table_Name[Column_Name] = TRUE()))
False_Measure = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table_Name, Table_Name[Column_Name] = FALSE()))
```

---

If you really want to use `COUNTAX`, then it would look like this:

```
True_Measure  = COUNTAX(FILTER(Table_Name, Table_Name[Column_Name] = TRUE()), 1)
False_Measure = COUNTAX(FILTER(Table_Name, Table_Name[Column_Name] = FALSE()), 1)
```

Comment: This does not work with `TRUE()` or `FALSE()`. Power BI returns an error message: `DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Text with values of type True/False. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values.`

Comment: It sounds like you have a text column rather than a Boolean column. You have to compare with the same type.